# Я хочу войти через парсер на сайт https://www.livejournal.com под своим логином и паролем. Как это сделать?

Tags: php, парсер, авторизация

Я хочу войти через парсер на сайт https://www.livejournal.com под своим логином и паролем. Как это сделать?

Comment: например: залогиниться в браузере, сохранить cookes, использовать эти cookies в дальнейшем.

Comment: Я не ввожу логин и пароль при каждом заходе на сайт. Мои логин и пароль уже есть в кокиесах. Но среди всех запросов и ответов я не могут найти именно тот ответ который сообщает сайту что я это я.

Comment: `Мои логин и пароль уже есть в кокиесах` — скорее всего, их там нет. но содержимого cookies достаточно для авторизации. просто используйте эти cookies.