# Необходимо авторизоваться на сайте emias.info используя request, BeautifulSoup и другие(Кроме Selenium)

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Привычная форма отсутствует. Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли это вообще. И если да, то как.

Comment: [дубликаты посыпались](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1454549/178576)

Comment: Если бы, излазил пол - интернета. Понять так и не смог. Вместо логин, пароль. Полис и дата рождения. id нет. Как отправляется форма не понятно. Скорее всего через csrf токен. И если это так, то что я могу сделать?